# Trouble producing list of dates in a customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime-format

I've written a script to produce list of dates. The script I've tried with can do it. However, the way I need the list of dates is very different from what I'm getting at this moment.

The script I've tried with:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,6,20)
daterange = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]
for idate in daterange:
    print(idate)
```

Current results are like:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00
2017-01-02 00:00:00
2017-01-03 00:00:00
2017-01-04 00:00:00
2017-01-05 00:00:00
2017-01-06 00:00:00
```

The way I expect to get the dates like:

```
01-01-2017 
01-02-2017  
01-03-2017  
01-04-2017  
01-05-2017  
01-06-2017
```

How can I modify my script to achieve the same? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `strftime` in `print`, for more details you can look into [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
print(idate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> %d : Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> %m : Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
>
> %Y: Year with century as a decimal number.

For testing the code above:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2017,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2017,6,20)
daterange = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]
for idate in daterange:
    print(idate.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

Result:

```
01-01-2017
02-01-2017
03-01-2017
04-01-2017
05-01-2017
06-01-2017
07-01-2017
08-01-2017
09-01-2017
.
.
.
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thanks a lot.